# WebSphere Application Server 7 doesn't understand security header in a Web Service response

Tags: java, web-services, security, websphere-7

I have an enterprise application consisting of a Web Service client running on WebSphere Application Server 7.

When I try to consume the service I receive a response (not a fault) which contains data I requested and then WebSphere raises the following exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security
```

The WebService is authenticated with Username token and doesn't use Message Level Protection.

I created my custom policy set (WS-Addressing & WS-Security), removed Message Level Protection, added custom binding with username and password.

I tested this with SoapUI and I get the same response (not a fault) from the Web Service as I get when using the WebSphere.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the attached policyset is not loaded properly.

Attached is a sample ws-security policy and binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512" xmlns:spe="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/200605/ws-securitypolicy-ext" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/1.0" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

  <sp:SupportingTokens>
    <wsp:Policy  wsu:Id="request:uname_token">
      <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:UsernameToken>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:SupportingTokens>
  <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
    </wsp:Policy>
  </sp:AsymmetricBinding>

</wsp:Policy>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<securityBindings xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/200608/ws-securitybinding">

 <securityBinding name="application">

  <securityOutboundBindingConfig>
    <tokenGenerator name="gen_unametoken" classname="com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.wssapi.token.impl.CommonTokenGenerator">
      <valueType localName="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken" uri="" />
      <callbackHandler classname="com.ibm.websphere.wssecurity.callbackhandler.UNTGenerateCallbackHandler">
        <basicAuth userid="user1" password="security"/>
      </callbackHandler>
      <jAASConfig configName="system.wss.generate.unt"/>
      <securityTokenReference reference="request:uname_token"/>
    </tokenGenerator>
    <timestampExpires expires="PT5M"/>
  </securityOutboundBindingConfig>

  <securityInboundBindingConfig>
    <!-- No security defined on client inbound for this configuration -->
  </securityInboundBindingConfig>

 </securityBinding>

</securityBindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was with Message Level protection. If I switch it on the problem disappears. I just have to make sure there are no parts specified to be encrypted, so the message doesn't get encrypted itself.